# Uploading XML string from C# to node.js/express server

Tags: c#, xml, node.js, http, express

I'm trying to upload a string (which is XML but for the purposes of uploading I'm trying to treat it as a regular string) to an express.js server which will then process the XML and send back a short string as a reply.

The XML is retrieved in a C# console app:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;

        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        string license = (string)farm.Properties["relevantpropertyretrievedhere"];

        string URI = "http://localhost:3000";
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        string reply = client.UploadString (URI, license);
        Console.WriteLine (reply);

    }
```

The string is being retrieved properly, but I included that code as well in case it was relevant. My express code is currently very simple:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.post('/', bodyParser.urlencoded(), function(req, res){
    console.log("Request received: " + req);
    var result = functionX(req);
   res.send(result);
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
```

From what I can tell by testing it, the C# app is sending a POST request and the server is receiving it, but I can't seem to extract the XML string from the POST. I'm not even sure it's in there. Recommendations? Is the fact that the string I'm sending is XML possibly messing it up? Is there a better way to send/receive HTTP requests in C# besides WebClient? Thank you for any help!